# Vintage electric car circuit problems

Tags: automotive, vintage

[image]

This circuit is in a vintage electric car. The 12 volt circuit works perfectly alone. The 36 volt circuit works perfectly alone. When both circuits are activated the contactor points bounce open and closed open and closed and the lights go on and off on and off.  What can I do to make this system function properly?  Thanks.  John

Comment: That is a very confusing picture.  Each battery will have a positive side and a negative side.  It looks like they are all connected together in that sketch.

Comment: What exactly is confusing? Start at the upper right corner and follow the 36 volt and 12 volt current to ground.

Comment: Starting in the upper right...??? well if you want to communicate with engineer's there are conventions to follow.

Comment: opps (I always hit return on comments to start a new sentence.)  Anyway I'm not sure how you power up the 12V w/o the 36.  But I'd guess it's in your switch where 12V is turning on 36?  I was going to post a better schematic, but I'm too lazy.  +1 for responding (why the minus?)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand of your circuit, it appears that the 36v supply can't provide **all the current** needed by the motor/controller, the 12v circuit, and the 36v contactor coil. The result is that the 36v supply voltage drops, causing the contactor points to open, reducing the load on the 36v supply, causing the voltage to rise, causing the contactor points to close, which causes the 36v supply voltage to drop, causing the contactor points to open, etc. ect..  This is what causes the opening and closing of the contactor points, as you report.